# Google language settings via email settings api

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-admin-sdk

I use email settings API to change user language setting.
But this API should be migrated to Gmail API.
I check new one but no capability to change user language setting.

I really need this function because we have a lot of over sea users.

Does everyone have same opinion ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the Migration guide.  [Migrating from the Email Settings API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings#managing_language_settings)

> Managing language settings
>   Languages settings are no longer available via the API.

This is not something that is supported any longer.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your reply.Yes I read this article.So I can't migrate this function...I have to stop it..

Comment: I have sent an email to Google trying to get some feedback on how developers should proceed with these not available methods. I have not heard back from them yet.

Comment: HI.Thank you very much.I hope we get a response from Google.

Comment: I linked this question and another one in my email if I hear back I will update this.

Comment: I appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the GSuite domain's `language` setting then all users created after that will have that set as their Gmail language. See the Admin SDK API here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/customers#language or in the Admin Console UI > Company Profile > Language.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work on Gmail and the Gmail API platform.*

**We're happy to announce that we have now released the new [Gmail API language settings methods](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/language_settings), effectively replacing the long since [deprecated Email Settings API language settings feature](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_language_settings).**

You can now use the standard libraries and tools found at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api to interact with the new Gmail API feature.

We will be publishing a blog post at https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com raising the visibility of the new language settings methods in the coming weeks, but I wanted to personally give you a courtesy heads-up.

#### Documentation

- Overview/introduction guide:
  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/language_settings
- Migration guide (from the deprecated [Email Settings API language
  settings feature](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_language_settings)):
  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings#managing_language_settings